# Как спарсить определенный текст с сайта Python?

Tags: python, html, requests, beautiful-soup

В общем, столкнулся с проблемой. Мне нужно спарсить количество просмотров с сайта "https://pcstonks.ru/note/".
Нужно получить только "61541" при помощи библиотек beautiful-soup и requests.
Я новичок в парсинге, поэтому это может быть глупый вопрос. Буду рад любой помощи.
[image: Screenshot]

```
r = requests.get('https://pcstonks.ru/note/qDhRaP', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
div = soup.select('div[class="fs-6 text-end"]')[0]
views = div.text.strip()
print(views)
```

этот код выводит

```
61541



Скачать
Поделиться
```

Comment: Правой кнопкой кликаете по тексту в инспекторе, наводите на пункт "копировать" там выбираете "копировать селектор" и получаете селектор для нужного узла.

Comment: ![ссылка](https://gachi.gay/Pswr3) не нахожу такого

Comment: `number_views = soup.find("button", class_="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light me-1 fs-6").get_text()`

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://pcstonks.ru/note/qDhRaP")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
total_views = soup.select_one("button.me-1").get_text(strip=True)
print(total_views) # 61749
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Быстрый ответ

Используйте следующий селектор: `div[class="fs-6 text-end"] button:first`. Поскольку выбранный div содержит еще и идущие дальше кнопки (лайк, дизлайк, поделиться и т.д.). А так будет выбрана конкретно первая кнопка, содержащая нужный текст.

#### Некоторые рекомендации

Разметка сайта может поменяться, что делает ваш код не слишком долговечным. Куда более долговечным решением может быть использование селекторов не по первым увиденным атрибутам, а по некоторой семантике. Например, здесь `fs-6 text-end` - классы, отвечающие за отображение элемента, но никак не указывающие на его смысл и содержимое. А вот вышележащий `div#noteButtons` звучит уже как нечто более устойчивое. С самим индикатором просмотров посложнее - его можно охарактеризовать тем, что текст внутри является числом, а также иконкой глаза. Иконка не сильно устойчива, но это лучшее, что имеем.

К сожалению, для такого не подойдут css-селекторы ввиду их ограниченной функциональности. Я бы рекомендовал использовать xpath, но для этого придется использовать lxml напрямую, BeautifulSoup такое не поддерживает. Получится следующий путь - `//*[@id='noteButtons']//button[.//i[contains(@class, 'fa-eye')] and string(number(text()))!='NaN']`.